# pear NET_DNS and get all DNS records at once

Tags: php, dns

I need to get all available DNS records with usage of pear NET_DNS. If you use dns_get_record it's simple as you have to just enter:

```
dns_get_record('http://example.com,DNS_ALL)
```

I used :

$DNS_obj->resolver->search("cnn.com","DNS_ALL");

Unfortunately **DNS_ALL** doesn't work with NET_DNS pear package.
I can use MX, A, NS and so on but not DNS_ALL.

I cannot use **dns_get_record** function as it's unavailable on MACs PHP installation.